# set times: Operation not permitted

Tags: timestamp, winscp

In WinSCP, If you have opened a file from the server on your local and on making changes and pressing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>), basically saving it, you get an error saying:

> /path of the file/ set times: Operation not permitted

And whenever you are saving the file, the error keeps on getting queued up due to which the files are not saved on the server end.

And in the end to save the files you will have to press OK on all of the dialog boxes one by one.

Why is it occurring ? How to tackle this problem ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This problem is occurring because WinSCP tries to preserve the time-stamp of the file, which in a way is a good thing as you will know which file is the latest.

But if you have set some restrictions on the server end, which is highly likely, the server will deny it and the error will appear.

To tackle the problem:

- *Transfer Settings* -> *Configure*
- A preferences box will open
- Double Click on *Default*
- Uncheck *Preserve Timestamp*

or

- *Options* -> *Preferences*
- A preferences box will open
- Click on *Transfer*
- Double Click on *Default*
- Uncheck *Preserve Timestamp*

See http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom

And now it will work and you won't see any errors. The only problem was occurring because of the synchronization of the file's timestamp.

Comment: With second option you could also set "[x] Ignore permission errors", so WinSCP will at least try to set timestamp but not bug you with an error message anymore.